# How to prevent floating context Menu on text selection in webview in Android 6.0

Tags: android, webview, contextmenu, android-6.0-marshmallow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCqkw.png)On text selection in android 6.0 a [context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBbGS.png) is showing containing options "SELECT ALL , COPY etc". How can I hide this or prevent this from showing?

Comment: Please see the image link and help me to get out of this issue " enter image description here".